# Jstree always_copy not working when copying nodes between trees

Tags: jquery-plugins, jstree, drag-and-drop

I am really stuck on a jstree issue; I have 2 trees a “source” tree and a “destination” tree. The “source” tree is a flat tree that contains nodes that I wish to drag over to the “destination” tree to build it out. But, after the drag I need those nodes to stay so I can reuse them. Now, if I press the control key down before and during the drag it will perform a copy function and leave the source node. But, I don’t want to have the user do this; I would like the tree to always copy. Which is why I used this setting, but it’s not working on my tree. Can anyone help? Here is the code, minus data, which causes this issue.
Thanks!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SourceTree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "Home/GetTree",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data": function (n) {
                        var result = "{'id':'" + (n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_", "") : "0") + "'}";                            
                        return (result);
                    }
                }
            },
            "crrm": {
                "move": {
                    "always_copy": "multitree",
                    // Do not allow a node move within this tree
                    "check_move": function () {
                        return false;
                    },
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types", "crrm", "dnd"]
        })

        $("#DestinationTree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "Home/GetTree",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data": function (n) {
                        var result = "{'id':'" + (n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_", "") : "0") + "'}";
                        return (result);
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types", "dnd", "crrm"]
        })
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out with lots of trial and error:
The source tree must have:
1) "dnd" & "crrm" plugs ins like the example does
2) The move.check_move function must be present as well as above
3) We do NOT need the move.always_copy, delete this, not needed here.

The destination tree must have:
1) "dnd" & "crrm" plugs ins like the example does
2) Needed to add the crrm.move.always_copy:true, here.
                "crrm": {
                    "move":
                    {
                        "always_copy": true
                    }
                },